How can I drill through my floor system for cable?
I am attempting to wire my house with cat 6.
General plan:
All of the bedrooms are on the second floor and the dining room is on the first floor. My plan was to fish a bundle of cables (8 to be exact 2 for each guest room 4 for the master bedroom) from the living room (where I would install a networking box) up to the attic and then drop down into the bedroom.
What is happening:
I am currently on the second floor trying to drill down to the first floor from the hollow gap between drywall and I keep having this odd problem of length; the current farthest hole (attempt 5) is 11 inches in depth. I have tried multiple holes in multiple areas and all of them seem to have the same problem of going what feels like way too far down. Attempts 1-3 were in the same section of drywall (between the same 2 studs) and attempts 4 and 5 were moved to the right to try and make it work. I am positive (check a lot) that the wall I am drilling leads into the same wall on the 1st floor.
Questions:
What am I doing wrong and what could I be drilling into? I don't think this is operator error. How much of a pain would it be to try and use an exterior wall for this project, and would insulation get in the way? If I do use an exterior wall do I just remove insulation where I want the networking box to go?

11 inches is not that far if the floors use 2x12 joists.  If drilling through a bottom plate of a wall, you have 1.5 inch for the plate, ~an inch of floor/sub floor, the depth of joist(about 9.5 to 11.5) plus the ceiling below.

I agree with crip659, and I often come at this problem from both sides where access allows (though alignment can be challenging).

The house was built in the 1970's (believe 74). To make sure I am understanding correctly I am most likely drilling into an I-joist and should be fine to continue/try frim the other side to make the holes meet.

Posting this as a comment because is doesn't really answer the question, but when I was running a lot of cable outside of finished walls, one of my go-to tools was a 16" long 1/4" drill bit.  It's a lot easier to drill a small hole to check alignment and then widen both sides when you're satisfied.  Plus, if you're off, a 1/4" hole is easier to patch.

Some pictures and/or sketches would sure help you here.

In 1974 an I-joist seems less likely than a plain lumber joist or beam.

As a point of clarification I'll mention I interpret holes "going too far down" to mean that you're drilling through solid wood many inches deep.
I can think of two structural possibilities that explain your result:

a floor joist runs parallel to and directly beneath the wall and you have the misfortune of hitting it with every attempt (or, it's a beam instead of a floor joist)
floor joists run perpendicular to the wall you're working in, but there is solid blocking between the joists which is installed directly below your wall

It would be good to determine which case you're in. Drilling out the full depth of blocking is an annoyingly long job but the removal of all that material from one bay of blocking isn't a big concern. Drilling out the full depth of a joist or beam is a big concern. I suggest you figure out which way the floor joists run. Have a look at the ceiling below. If the drywall texture is light you may be able to see visually where the nails or screws are located. If not, you can determine joist location and direction with a stud finder.
Chris O gives a good suggestion for confirming the alignment between the floors is as you believe it to be. If the 2nd floor flooring is wall-to-wall carpet you can pull it back from the wall a bit and drill through the subfloor in front of the wall; the carpet will hide your hole. You'd discover whether there is solid wood here too. You can continue with the 1/4" drill to make a hole through the ceiling below also, or you can switch to something thinner like a straightened wire coat hanger to make a smaller hole in the drywall. Almost anything will drill through a drywall ceiling.
Hopefully better knowledge of the floor structure you're working with and evidence that the vertical alignment is correct will help you plot a path forward.

Thank you for your advice, discovered that I should not have been drilling into that wall (joists were running parallell so I am assuming one was running where I was trying to drill) and was able to find a new wall to use (after making sure a joist was not running under).
